# Only one link comes up on dual PCIe 10-Gigabit card

Tags: dell, ubuntu-16.04, gigabit-ethernet, pci-express, sr-iov

### Background

- A server running Ubuntu 16.04
- Dell X520 (based on Intel's 82599) is connected via PCIe
- **ixgbe** driver was installed from [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/14687/Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-PCIe-Intel-10-Gigabit-Ethernet-Network-Connections-Under-Linux-?product=32609) and comes up at boot

### Issue

The card is recognized by the driver - but only one link is being set up, i.e. interface `eth1` is working properly (and sends and receives traffic, bla bla) but `eth0` isn't.

Any ideas?

### Working on it

ip link

```
# ip link
6: enp4s0f0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1b:21:66:a3:e0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: enp4s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1b:21:66:a3:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

dmesg

```
# dmesg | grep -ie ixgbe
[    3.619850] ixgbe: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    3.716062] ixgbe: 0000:04:00.0: ixgbe_check_options: FCoE Offload feature enabled
[    4.133037] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: PCI Express bandwidth of 32GT/s available
[    4.133059] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: (Speed:5.0GT/s, Width: x8, Encoding Loss:20%)
[    4.133573] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0 eth0: MAC: 2, PHY: 19, SFP+: 9, PBA No: G18786-001
[    4.133586] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: 00:1b:21:66:a3:e0
[    4.133602] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0 eth0: Enabled Features: RxQ: 16 TxQ: 16 FdirHash
[    4.235706] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0 eth0: Intel(R) 10 Gigabit Network Connection
[    4.267633] ixgbe: 0000:04:00.1: ixgbe_check_options: FCoE Offload feature enabled
[    4.485259] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: PCI Express bandwidth of 32GT/s available
[    4.498568] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: (Speed:5.0GT/s, Width: x8, Encoding Loss:20%)
[    4.512331] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1 eth1: MAC: 2, PHY: 19, SFP+: 10, PBA No: G18786-001
[    4.525753] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: 00:1b:21:66:a3:e1
[    4.538963] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1 eth1: Enabled Features: RxQ: 16 TxQ: 16 FdirHash
[    4.552185] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1 eth1: Intel(R) 10 Gigabit Network Connection
[    4.565850] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1 enp4s0f1: renamed from eth1
[    4.587784] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0f0: renamed from eth0
[    9.730465] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: registered PHC device on enp4s0f0
[    9.904203] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0f0: detected SFP+: 9
[    9.927080] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: registered PHC device on enp4s0f1
[   10.093085] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1 enp4s0f1: detected SFP+: 10
[   12.664418] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1 enp4s0f1: NIC Link is Up 1 Gbps, Flow Control: None
```

lshw

```
# lshw | grep -ie 82599
       *-network:0
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
            logical name: enp4s0f0
            version: 01
            serial: 00:1b:21:66:a3:e0
            capacity: 1Gbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ixgbe driverversion=5.3.4 firmware=0x546d0001, 16.5.20 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
            resources: irq:52 memory:91c80000-91cfffff ioport:2020(size=32) memory:91f04000-91f07fff memory:92180000-921fffff memory:91f08000-92007fff memory:92008000-92107fff
       *-network:1
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 0.1
            bus info: pci@0000:04:00.1
            logical name: enp4s0f1
            version: 01
            serial: 00:1b:21:66:a3:e1
            size: 1Gbit/s
            capacity: 1Gbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ixgbe driverversion=5.3.4 duplex=full firmware=0x546d0001, 16.5.20 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
            resources: irq:70 memory:91c00000-91c7ffff ioport:2000(size=32) memory:91d00000-91d03fff memory:91d04000-91e03fff memory:91e04000-91f03fff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The card did not support the specific SFP I used.

Changing to a different one did the trick.